# Cannot scroll on React App even on page overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently working on the Body portion for a Spotify clone using ReactJS. I am fairly new to Javascript, HTML, and CSS so apologies for any oversights.

I am having a problem where I cannot scroll down to the bottom of the playlists page even when there are more tracks to be shown. I have tried adding 'overflow-y: scroll' to my CSS which renders a scroll bar but even then, the page cannot be scrolled (see right scrollbar in screenshot below). I have included my Body.jsx below.

[Screenshot of Spotify clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx5Hd.jpg)

**Body.jsx**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {AiFillClockCircle} from "react-icons/ai";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useStateProvider } from '../utils/StateProvider';
import { reducerCases } from "../utils/Constants";

export default function Body() {
    const[ {token, selectedPlaylistId, selectedPlaylist} ,dispatch] = useStateProvider();
    useEffect(() => {
        const getInitialPlaylist = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${selectedPlaylistId}`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                }
            );
            const selectedPlaylist = {
                id: response.data.id,
                name: response.data.name,
                description: response.data.description.startsWith("<a") ? "" : response.data.description,
                image: response.data.images[0].url,
                tracks: response.data.tracks.items.map(({track}) => ({ 
                    id: track.id,
                    name: track.name,
                    artists: track.artists.map((artist) => artist.name), 
                    image: track.album.images[2].url,
                    duration: track.duration_ms,
                    album: track.album.name, 
                    context_uri: track.album.uri, 
                    track_number: track.track_number, 


                })),
            };
            dispatch({type: reducerCases.SET_PLAYLIST,selectedPlaylist});
 
        };
        getInitialPlaylist(); 

    },[token,dispatch, selectedPlaylistId]);
  
    return ( 
        <Container>
        {
            selectedPlaylist && (
                <>
                    <div className="playlist">
                        <div className="image">
                            <img src={selectedPlaylist.image} alt="selectedplaylist" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="details">
                            <span className="type">PLAYLIST</span> 
                            <h1 className="title">{selectedPlaylist.name}</h1>
                            <p className="description">{selectedPlaylist.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <div className="list">
                        <div className="header__row">
                            <div className="col">
                                <span>#</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                                <span>TITLE</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                                <span>ALBUM</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                                <span><AiFillClockCircle /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div className="tracks">
                            {
                                selectedPlaylist.tracks.map(( {id,name,artists,image,duration,album,context_uri,track_number},index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="row" key={id}>
                                            <div className="col">
                                                <span>{index+1}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col detail">
                                                <div className="image">
                                                    <img src={image} alt="track" />
                                                </div>

                                                <div className="info">
                                                    <span className="name">{name}</span>
                                                    <span>{artists}</span>
                                                </div>                                       
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col">
                                                <span>{album}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col">
                                                <span>{duration}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                    
                                })
                            }
                        </div>  

                    </div>

                </>
            )
        }
        </Container>

    );
}

//CSS for styled components
const Container = styled.div`
overflow-y: scroll;  //scroll bar appears but doesn't scroll
.playlist {
    margin: 0 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    .image {
      img {
        height: 15rem;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 25px 50px -12px;
      }
    }
    .details {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 1rem;
      color: #e0dede;
      .title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 4rem;
      }
    }
  }
  .list {
    .header__row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 3fr 2fr 0.1fr;
      margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
      color: #dddcdc;
      position: sticky;
      top: 15vh;
      padding: 1rem 3rem;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .tracks {
      margin: 0 2rem;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
      .row {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 3.1fr 2fr 0.1fr;
        &:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }
        .col {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          color: #dddcdc;
          img {
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
          }
        }
        .detail {
          display: flex;
          gap: 1rem;
          .info {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
    
    
`;
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how I can get the page to be scrollable, I would greatly appreciate it. I have done lots of research but nothing has worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Try using `overflowY: 'scroll',`

Comment: @Kameron that just made the scrollbar disappear for some reason.

Comment: This is not related to react.js. Please create a snippet that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same project and faced the same issue.
I figured out that the issue lied in Spotify.jsx file.

Let this be the code:

```
 .body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
&::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.7rem;
  max-height: 2rem;
  &-thumb {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  }
}
```

}